# postgresql upgrade backup and restore same port

Tags: postgresql, backup, upgrade, port, restore

Here, I want to upgrade postgresql from 8.3(port 5432) to 9.0(port 5433)
Whats happen if,

```
-First I instal the postgres new version 9.0 on port 5433
-Than I backup and restore database by using comman,

 /usr/local/pgsql/bin/ pg_dumpall -U -h  -p 5432|psql -U  -p 5433 -h

-After that I stop both server 8.3 and 9.0
-By using pgAdmin III, I change port the server 9.0 from 5433 to 5432.
```

Whats happen if I try to upgrade with that way?

thanks :)

Comment: Are you certain that it's worth the hassle to have both installations on the same system just to do the pipe trick for migrating the database?

Answer (score 2):

This would work. This should also be faster than writing to file, as less writes will be needed. But remember to put old database in single user mode (`postgres --single ...`) so nobody would write to the database during migration.

You can also use [pg_upgrade](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html) to upgrade database in place. But check for [limitations while upgrading from 8.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html#AEN125354).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is my first question in here :D , But when I try to upgrade with pg_upgrade that's so complicated. And i had one question again. whats risk if i try to upgrade postgresql with  my way?

Comment: Your way is even safer than pg_upgrade, as this type of upgrades are new to Postgres and not as thoroughly tested as dump/restore.

Answer (score 1):

As Tometzky has already said, this should work.

Just to make the picture complete:

With 9.0 you can also use pg_upgrade for the migration which should be even faster than using pg_dump with a pipe.